# Oracle: Creating view across schemas?

Tags: oracle, view, schema

I'm trying to create a view, and have distilled the problem down to the inability to create a view that references tables from a different schema.

For example, I can do:

```
select count(*) from otherschema.othertable;
```

and I can do:

```
create view foo as select count(*) as bar from oneofmytables;
```

But if I try:

```
create view foo as select count(*) as bar from otherschema.othertable;
```

I get an "insufficient privileges" error.  What additional privileges do I need?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you have the grant to the other user's table directly?  Or is it via a role?  You will need the privilege to be granted directly in order to create an object (view, procedure, etc.) that references the other table.  As a quick test, in SQL*Plus

```
SQL> set role none;
SQL> select count(*) from otherschema.othertable;
```

If that fails, then the problem is that you have been granted privileges on the table via a role.

Comment: Both good, correct answers, but I picked this one because it easily allowed me to verify the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I guess you have been given select right on `otherschema.othertable` via a `role` not via a direct `grant`.

If this is the case, you should connect as `otheruser` and then do a `grant select on othertable to <your-schema>`.

Comment: And if the view is expected to be selected from a third schema, add WITH GRANT OPTION to the GRANT.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your DBA will need to grant you

> create any view

privilege.  Depending on the security restrictions at your site they may or not allow this. I typically do not